# Byte buddy stack manipulation: how to work with local variables and if statements

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Generally, the questions are:

- How and at which moment ByteBuddy generates local variables table and stackmap frames?
- What is the correct way to work with local variables and generate if statements in ByteBuddy's `Implementation` API?

Details:

I am using bytebuddy for generating equals methods of some classes. For that purpose, I am using custom implementation of `net.bytebuddy.implementation.Implementation`. In theory, the bytecode I am planning to generate is supposed to have almost the following semantics:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final T other = (T) obj;
    if (this.a != other.a) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.b, other.b)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The code above has one local variable and several *if*s. I haven't found official `StackManipulation`'s for both of them, so:

- For working with locals, I use `MethodVariableAccess.REFERENCE.loadFrom` and `MethodVariableAccess.REFERENCE.storeAt`
- For generating if statements, I use custom implementations of `StackManipulation`s

like:

```
interface Branching extends StackManipulation {
    @Override
    default boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }

    class Mark implements Branching {

        private final Label label;

        public Mark(Label label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public final Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context ctx) {
            mv.visitLabel(label);
            return new Size(0, 0);
        }
    }

    class IfNe implements Branching {

        private final Label label;

        public IfNe(Label label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public final Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context ctx) {
            mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IFNE, label);
            return new Size(-2, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like I am doing it wrong, because the generated bytecode misses both local variables table and stackmap frames. And it doesn't pass verification of course, complaining that "Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target X".

UPDATE:

I think it is worth to add an example here. Initial case I was talking about was quite large, so I wrote a module anew to demonstrate an issue. It's quite large, but I can't imagine how to make it smaller:

```
package com.xxx.proba.bytebuddy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.description.field.FieldDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.description.modifier.Visibility;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.Implementation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.ByteCodeAppender;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.StackManipulation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.collection.ArrayAccess;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.constant.IntegerConstant;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.constant.TextConstant;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.member.FieldAccess;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.member.MethodInvocation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.member.MethodReturn;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.member.MethodVariableAccess;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.Label;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.MethodVisitor;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.Opcodes;


/**
 * Assuming that I want to generate the class like this one
 * 
 * @author skapral
 */
class ExampleClass {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        if (args[0].equals("")) {
            System.out.println("a");
        } else {
            System.out.println("b");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    private final static Method EQUALS;
    private final static Method PRINTLN;
    private final static Field SYSTEM_OUT;

    static {
        try {
            EQUALS = Object.class.getMethod("equals", Object.class);
            PRINTLN = PrintStream.class.getMethod("println", String.class);
            SYSTEM_OUT = System.class.getField("out");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DynamicType.Unloaded<Object> unloaded = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("com.echelon.proba.bytebuddy.ExampleClassGenerated")
                .defineMethod("main", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
                .withParameter(String[].class)
                .intercept(new Implementation() {
                    @Override
                    public ByteCodeAppender appender(Implementation.Target implementationTarget) {
                        return new ByteCodeAppender() {
                            @Override
                            public ByteCodeAppender.Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context ctx, MethodDescription md) {
                                Label ifLabel = new Label();
                                Label elseLabel = new Label();

                                StackManipulation.Size size = new StackManipulation.Compound(
                                        MethodVariableAccess.REFERENCE.loadFrom(1),
                                        IntegerConstant.ZERO,
                                        ArrayAccess.REFERENCE.load(),
                                        new TextConstant(""),
                                        MethodInvocation.invoke(new MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod(EQUALS)), 
                                        new IfEq(ifLabel),
                                        FieldAccess.forField(new FieldDescription.ForLoadedField(SYSTEM_OUT)).read(),
                                        new TextConstant("a"),
                                        MethodInvocation.invoke(new MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod(PRINTLN)),
                                        new GoTo(elseLabel),
                                        new Mark(ifLabel),
                                        FieldAccess.forField(new FieldDescription.ForLoadedField(SYSTEM_OUT)).read(),
                                        new TextConstant("b"),
                                        MethodInvocation.invoke(new MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod(PRINTLN)),
                                        new Mark(elseLabel),
                                        MethodReturn.VOID
                                ).apply(mv, ctx);
                                return new Size(size.getMaximalSize(), md.getStackSize());
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public InstrumentedType prepare(InstrumentedType instrumentedType) {
                        return instrumentedType;
                    }
                })
                .make();
        unloaded.saveIn(new File("/tmp/aaa")); /* Preserve it for future investigation by javap */
        Object obj = unloaded.load(Main.class.getClassLoader()).getLoaded().newInstance();
        obj.getClass().getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(obj, new String[] {"aaa"}); /* Trigger class loading and verification */
    }
}


class IfEq implements StackManipulation {
    private final Label label;

    public IfEq(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public StackManipulation.Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context ctx) {
        mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IFEQ, label);
        return new StackManipulation.Size(-1, 0);
    }
}

class GoTo implements StackManipulation {
    private final Label label;

    public GoTo(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public StackManipulation.Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context ctx) {
        mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, label);
        return new StackManipulation.Size(0, 0);
    }
}

class Mark implements StackManipulation {
    private final Label label;

    public Mark(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public StackManipulation.Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context ctx) {
        mv.visitLabel(label);
        return new StackManipulation.Size(0, 0);
    }
}
```

In that example, in Main::main method, I'm trying to generate simple ExampleClass by bytebuddy. On attempt to load it and call a method, I got VerifyError.

```
  Location:
    com/echelon/proba/bytebuddy/ExampleClassGenerated.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @8: ifeq
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b03 3212 08b6 000c 9900 0eb2 0012 1214
    0x0000010: b600 1aa7 000b b200 1212 1cb6 001a b1  

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at com.xxx.proba.bytebuddy.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

UPDATE: Just to summarize: this simple AsmVisitorWrapper helped me:

```
public class EnableFramesComputing implements AsmVisitorWrapper {
    @Override
    public final int mergeWriter(int flags) {
        return flags | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES;
    }

    @Override
    public final int mergeReader(int flags) {
        return flags | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES;
    }

    @Override
    public final ClassVisitor wrap(TypeDescription td, ClassVisitor cv, Implementation.Context ctx, TypePool tp, FieldList<FieldDescription.InDefinedShape> fields, MethodList<?> methods, int wflags, int rflags) {
        return cv;
    }
}
```

It can be placed in action by calling visit on DynamicType.Builder, like:

```
DynamicType.Unloaded<Object> unloaded = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .visit(new EnableFramesComputing())
            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte Buddy intends to be a high-level byte code manipulation library. If you want to create low-level byte code, you should most likely use ASM directly which is a great tool for doing so.

ASM offers to compute stack map frames by setting the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` flag. You can set the flag by registering an `AsmVisitorWrapper` that only sets that flag without registering a wrapper.

If you want to create custom byte code, did you consider the `Advice` component? It allows you to write the code in plain Java where the byte code is inlined at runtime and mapped to the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I'll think about it. Speaking about 'high-level' status of the tool. It looks strange to have such discrimination for branching opcodes. Bytebuddy's StackManipulation is really nice abstraction, much nicer then ASM's visitors. And it actually seem to allow working on low level in hard cases. That's why I really don't understand your point - why my case is considered as something which ByteBuddy is not designed for?

Comment: Anyway, AsmVisitorWrapper is indeed a way out. Thank you. I'll accept this answer as soon as I make all the necessary checks and investigations.

Comment: I considered adding this functionality and maybe I will at some point. This bears the problem of keeping track of the stack state what is non trivial qnd brings some overhead. Nice APIs are often not fast but people using low level APIs typically require that.

Comment: Did you end up using AsmVisitorWrapper to do this? if so can you post the resulting code? I'm trying to do something similar where I need to use ASM for the implementation and there is a lot of branching.